# How do i use iBooks or an alternative app across my devices for PDF annotations

Tags: ios, pdf, books

I've never been able to get this to work so must be doing something wrong. I'm trying to read this [PDF](http://www.diveintopython3.net)(The link is at the bottom of the page) and be able to add notes on my iPad say, but then be able to read it on my iPhone and see the notes/add more notes to it. Problems I often have are having to make a copy of it on each device as it can't be saved or it's in my iBooks on one device but not another (eg - I have a Pro Git book in my phone, but it's never made it to my iPad). I've tried a coupe of different apps and read links also, so I must be missing something fundamental.

Comment: Depending on the PDF viewer, you could store the PDFs in the cloud, such as on Dropbox. They say that synching does work in that environment.

Comment: @MaxWyss Thanks Mike, any particular PDF viewers where this works? So there isn't some common Apple way to achieve this, which surprises me

Comment: @Jonny: Mike who??? PDF viewers which do work this way (and for this purpose): PDFExpert by Readdle, Adobe Reader for iOS, and some more.

Comment: Sorry Max! :) Thank you for the help with the answer too, feel free to put it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by the OP, from the comments:

Depending on the PDF viewer, the PDFs could be stored in the cloud, using something like Dropbox. Synching is supposed to work in this environment.

If it is just for commenting, decent PDF viewers are Adobe Reader or iOS, or (in any case) PDFExpert by Readdle.